# Pie chart taking more load time than line chart in highchart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart with around 2300 points. It takes a lot of time to load. When I changed the chart to line chart, it loads faster. I have created a jsfiddle of the same.

> In this example, the line chart loads in less than 1 second. But Pie
>   chart takes around 4 seconds to load the chart.

anyone know why is it so?

I have set `turboThreshold: 0,`

[This is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/682oh5e3/8/)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

For charts with big amount of data you can try the boost module for faster loading.

Here you can download the module, read how to use it and see working examples:

[Boost Module Doc](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-high-performance-boost-module/)

But i am afraid the pie chart is not supported yet so you have to choose another chart type.

Answer (score 0):

The difference result from the default configurations, which is different for `line` and `pie` series types. If we disable `animation` and `dataLabels`, the performance will be very similar. The remaining difference is caused by different calculations in the series creation process and slices that are always rendered in contrast to the markers on a `line` series.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qspvf3zt/

**Reported issue:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11447